# Python Selenium Wire Webdriver not utilizing Page Load Strategy

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, seleniumwire

**Edit: There are other questions addressing the ability to interact with pages that aren't fully loaded. THIS IS NOT THAT. This is specific to the SeleniumWire driver, not just Selenium Webdriver.**

I'm currently working with a project using Selenium with Chromedriver in Python 3.8, which requires manipulating a page that takes a very long time to load. As such, I'm using the page loading strategy 'eager' `options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'` in order to be able to manipulate certain elements of the page before it loads fully.

I set up a test that measures the time for an element to be clicked after the browser has been declared. (Effectively measuring how long the page loading is taking to the point where a constant button can be clicked). When I used the regular Selenium Webdriver, running 15 tests got me an average time of **0.7352** seconds. However, when I used the SeleniumWire Webdriver (with the **only** change being the change in the difference of Webdriver), my load times after 15 tests were on average **4.3745**. These load times were on par as when I ran this test on Selenium Webdriver using the 'normal' (or default) page load strategy which after 15 tests were on average **4.3900**.

Thus, I believe that SeleniumWire is not utilizing the page load strategy and I was looking for possible solutions. How can I make sure that SeleniumWire uses eager loading?